# Converting String to JSON in Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

Moving data from SQL Server to Cosmos in Copy Activity of Data Factory v2. One of the column in SQL server has JSON object (Although dataType is (`varchar(MAX)`) and I have mapped it to one column  in Cosmos collection. The issue is it adds it as `String` NOT json object. How can we setup it up in Copy Activity so that data for that one particular column gets added as Json Object not string

It gets added as follows:

```
MyObject:"{SomeField: "Value" }"
```

However I want this to be:

```
MyObject:{SomeField: "Value" } // Without quotes so that it appears as json object rather than string
```

Comment: Turned out to be a known issue https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/32014042-json-data-should-not-convert-to-string-while-impor

Comment: Please summarize it as an answer to end this case.

Answer (score 2):

Use **JSON** conversion function available in Data Factory.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#json

```
MyObject:json("{SomeField: "Value" }")
```

It will result as

```
MyObject:{SomeField: "Value" }
```

Comment: Hi, 
I can't find this function in expression builder of a derived column. Could you tell exactly where to find it ?  I use ADF V2
Thanks :)